# Send mail from plain HTML

Tags: html, email

How to send a mail using plain `HTML` language. Something like, when we click on the link, it should open the outlook automatically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
Click <a href="mailto:name@provider.org?subject=Your Subject&body=Your Contents of the mail.">here</a> to mail.
```

Note: `subject` and `body` is optional.